# What's the weapon this dragonborn has?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, content-identification

There's an illustration on page 45 of the Draconomicon for D&D 4e, excerpted in this image:

[image]

What is the name of the weapon the dragonborn in this picture is holding?
I'm looking for a statted weapon (if there is one) or confirmation that there isn't a statted weapon in a guide or reference. Preferably I'd like to find a pathfinder version, even though the art is from the draconomicon from 4th ed.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79400/what-is-the-correct-name-for-the-style-of-sword-the-uruk-hai-use

Comment: @Voromir Kaiden it would be if i were actually asking about the uruk hai "scimitars", but the image is from an existing D&D 4th sourcebook, which following my logic means somewhere in the D&D library there has to be something that fits the bill. If not then cool, but still.

Comment: Is anyone else confused by the geometry of the blade in that image? It looks like at the handle the dragonborn is holding it so it's edge is pointed straight down at the ground, but then as it passes behind the character on the right it twists so it's parallel to the ground instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D&D's weapon descriptions are usually fairly broad such that many weapons which would have different names and classifications in the real world fall under one mechanical umbrella in the rules, and within the general shape of the weapon you get a lot of free reign to describe the details.

Based on being a large, broad-bladed curved sword the weapon depicted would probably be best described as a falchion, were it not for the fact that it's being wielded one-handed. If limited to the PHB core it might be either a longsword, scimitar, or bastard sword, but the Adventurer's Vault introduces some new weapons that could also fit the bill - the [khopesh](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Khopesh), which is a kind of axe-sword, or the [broadsword](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Broadsword), as it is very broad-bladed compared to the standard image of a bastard sword/longsword.

The odds however are very unlikely that the artist of the image had a particular weapon type in mind when they produced the piece.

Answer (score -3):

That looks like some sort of chinese dao. With a spike from uruk hai cleaver from LOTR films. I would look for something like a big sabre or a cleaver. ... In 4e a falchion or a scimitar.

Comment: So it is probably a weapon modified through the system and not a stand alone weapon somewhere in some kind of obscure book, you reckon?